# How to delete file in fileList using nzRemoved in Angular7

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, angular7, ng-zorro-antd

I have a fileList from upload file using Nz Zorro Ant for html in Angular 7, data will post to database using Spring Boot API, I want to use [nzRemoved] to delete file in fileList. How to use it?

This is my .ts,

```
    checkUpload(event) {
    // console.log(event);
    // this.payload = JSON.stringify(event.file.response);
    if (event.type === 'success'){
    // (<Array<any>>this.fileList).pop();
    this.fileList.push({
        uid   : event.file.uid,
        name  : event.file.name,
        status: event.file.status,
        url   : event.file.response.data[0].path_url
    });
    // this.payload = JSON.stringify(this.fileList);
    this.project.doc_url = JSON.stringify(this.fileList);
    this.projectOverviewService.postDocument(this.project_id, 
    this.fileList).subscribe( res => {
      console.log('success');
        });
     }
   }

  handleRemove(){
     for (let i = 0; i <= this.fileList.length; i++) {
     this.fileList.splice(0 , i) 
     }
  }
```

And this is my html,

```
  <div nz-col nzSpan="6" >
  <nz-upload 
  nzAction="/upload/documents" 
  [(nzFileList)]="fileList" 
  (nzChange)="checkUpload($event)" 
  [nzRemove]="handleRemove">
    <button nz-button type="button"><i nz-icon nzType="upload"></i> 
      <span>Upload dokumen Overview</span></button>
  </nz-upload>
  </div>
```

When I add [nzRemoved], removing file button in UI can not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code like this::

### HTML

```html
    <div nz-col nzSpan="6" >
      <nz-upload 
      nzAction="/upload/documents" 
      [(nzFileList)]="fileList" 
      (nzChange)="checkUpload($event)" 
      [nzRemove]="handleRemove">
        <button nz-button type="button"><i nz-icon nzType="upload"></i> 
          <span>Upload dokumen Overview</span></button>
      </nz-upload>
      </div>
```

### JS

```js
    handleRemove= (file: any) => new Observable<boolean>((obs) => {

    }
```